# Há perda de desempenho por utilizar alias no oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, alias

No oracle há alguma perda de desempenho, mesmo que pequena, ao utilizar alias para tabelas?

Exemplos:

```
select user.name from user;
```

e

```
select u.name from user u;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Aliases* não impactam a performance de uma query.

*Aliases* se referem a tabelas e colunas, sendo possível executar a query sem eles, por isso não impactam na execução, uma vez que nomes de colunas e tabelas são avaliados antes da execução, antes mesmo do motor do Oracle determinar o melhor plano de execução.

O que impacta a quer são as colunas utilizadas, a tabelas e a forma como são ligadas e pricipalmente o que vem no `where`, `order`, `group`, etc.

Para ter certeza, criei um tabela com uma estrutura semalhante a sua, executei a query com e sem alias e mostrei o plano de execução das duas, que foi o mesmo.

O resultado pode ser visto aqui:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4cc9/2

```
| Id | Operation        | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0  | SELECT STATEMENT |               | 8168  | 16336 | 29 (0)     | 00:00:01 |
| 1  | COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH| 8168  | 16336 | 29 (0)     | 00:00:01 |
```

Se quiser testar, ou ainda se o link falhar, aqui o script:

```
create table user_test (
   id int,
   name varchar(29)
);

insert into user_test values (1,'fulano');
insert into user_test values (2,'sicrano');

explain plan for
  SELECT name FROM user_test;

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());

explain plan for
  SELECT u.name FROM user_test u;

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());
```